# ASP.NET Core read content files while debugging

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have some json files that I need to read from my asp.net core app. They are under a folder called data

```
--MyProject
---Startup.cs
---Data
------dataset1.json
------dataset2.json
```

I am using IHostingEnvironment ContentRootPath to read the files:

```
 string pathToFile = hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath
                            + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
                            + "Data"
                            + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
                            + "dataset1.json"
```

which returns `C:\SourceControl\Test.Backend\src\Test.Web\Data\dataset1.json`

This works fine when I publish my code in IIS. However when I am debugging the files are copied into bin folder and the above code does not work.
How can I read the files while debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#if DEBUG

 string pathToFile = hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath
                        + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
                        + "bin"
                        + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
                        + "Data"
                        + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
                        + "dataset1.json"

#else

string pathToFile = hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath
                        + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
                        + "Data"
                        + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
                        + "dataset1.json"

#endif
```

you can have two different paths when you are in debug mode and in production with this approach. Just change the first path to your needs

Comment: That is what I had in mind but I wanted to avoid this solution with conditional compilation vars

Comment: `Path.Combine` method is more standard and lightweight for joining path parts (and probably a bit more efficient too).